# Composer setup-config.php not found

Tags: php, composer

I'm trying to install WordPress on my localhost with composer. When I go to localhost I get redirected to localhost/wp-admin/setup-config.php. Instead of getting the install I'm getting the error The requested URL /wp-admin/setup-config.php was not found on this server. When i go to localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/setup-config.php it works? What am I doing wrong?

This is my directory tree :

```
-- .git
-- .gitignore
-- composer.json
-- composer.lock
-- vendor

-- htdocs
----- index.php
----- wp-content
----- wordpress
----- wp-config
```

In the `htdocs/index.php` I have this

```
define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);
require( dirname ( __FILE__ ) . '/wordpress/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

And in my `htdocs/wp-config` I edited this :

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . '/wordpress');
define('WP_HOME',    'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
define('WP_CONTENT_DIR', dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-content');
define('WP_CONTENT_URL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . '/wp-content');
```

Comment: What do you have in `wp-config.php` (other than passwords etc.) & `.htaccess` (apache) or NginX configuration?

Comment: @Fayaz i've updated the question!

Answer (score 1):

Your WordPress is installed under the `localhost/wordpress/` instead of `localhost/`. If you are running your WordPress for the first time, point your url to `localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/install.php` so that the correct path can be setup by the WordPress.

Comment: Where do I change that?

Comment: It is perfectly fine to run your wordpress at `localhost/wordpress/` as is, but if you prefer to run it from `localhost/`, move all the files in the `wordpress` directory to `hotdocs` and change the `WP_SITEURL` setting to the same as `WP_HOME` setting in the `wp-config.php`.